# I'm trying to run a program in Java and I don't understand why it's not working

Tags: java, jpanel

I am trying to run this program in Java:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelTest extends JPanel

{public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

  {g.setColor(Color.green);

  g.drawString("Hello World",30,100);

  }

}
```

When I run it shows a box in which it's written:

> No main methods,applets or MIDlets found in file.

I don't understand what do I have to do.
Can someone explain this to me. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: A screenshot of the error? Some information about what IDE you are using? How are you running your program? How did you compile it?

And format your code properly...

Comment: Start with a basic Java tutorial.  Your program is incomplete and cannot run.

Comment: why is it incomplete? I don't understand what else do I have to write.

Comment: I am using JGrasp

Comment: @Eii, just a tip, NEVER use JGRASP. I start with Jgrasp too, but just made me confused. Eclipse or netBeans is very better for learn

Comment: yeah but Eclipse is harder to install so I found easier to install JGrasp that's why I'm using it.

Answer (score 2):

Every Java program requires a `public static void main (String[] args)` as main method. This method is the program's entry point. Everything starts from there.

You can then instantiate the Panel in that main method.

Something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(new PanelTest());
    frame.setVisible();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the error text, the problem is that you do not have a main method for your program. All Java programs must have a main method, since that is the starting point for Java Applications.

A typical main class for your simple application would be:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]){
      PanelTest pt = new PanelTest();

      pt.paintComponent(..);
   }

}
```

In the above, replace the '..' with the actual method arguments. I would definitely going through the basic concepts of Java. There are some great tutorials out there.

Comment: I don't understand what do i have to replace the '...' with? Which arguments?Can you explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Every Java program should be started with a `main` method:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Starting code here
}
```